# Browser infected Pop-up

Tags: samsung, browser, malware

Today I opened my mailbox in my new Samsung galaxy J7 and this screen appeared:

> **WARNING  Your Samsung galaxy j7's browser is still infected with a
>   serious virus! Continue with instructions to fix the phone. Do not close
>   this window.**Exit at your own risk.**

When I pressed OK, it took me to UPDATE BROWSER, and on pressing 'back' the phone started vibrating crazily! As the alert was from GOOGLE, I decided to go with it and pressed 'UPDATE BROWSER', it took me to a new page `sitex.dmtracker001.com`, but luckily error 400 appeared and it didn't connect.

The warning and vibration didn't go away until I restarted the phone, but it appeared again after some time and nothing I do makes it go away.

I don't know what to do, please help me.

Comment: You most likely visited some shady website and/or installed a very bad app. Go through the list of recently installed apps and remove the one(s) that seem like they would cause such things (like wallpaper apps that also require *all* permissions).

Answer (score 1):

First - as you  are probably aware now.  You NEVER click on a link from an unknown source. I repeat - NEVER. Next time, just close the window without clicking on any links Second - if you can't figure out which malware app was installed , you need to consider doing a factory reset on your phone to eliminate all threats.   A factory reset will erase the data (Text messages, photos, videos, settings, everything on your phone will be removed in the reset process.).... I would do it anyway just to be certain that I got it all.  You may be able to backup any pictures or video.  The easy way to reset is to go to Settings -> backup and recovery -> Reset Device -> Erase everything.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much have been cleared by comment and answer. But in this case a single of **clearing cookies** from your browser will help you to get rid from that pop up.

Other wise you can do factory reset. I have been passed through such situation.